# Document listener brings a null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jtable, jtextfield, documentlistener

I use a document listener and it brings me a null pointer exception . How could I stop this exception . I use this for search some content of a table. With using this I could search relevant content . Also this brings me a null pointer exception .

These are the steps,

In the beginning,

```
Vector originalTableModel;
DocumentListener documentListener;
```

In the counstructor,

```
originalTableModel = (Vector) ((DefaultTableModel) list_table.getModel()).getDataVector().clone();
//add document listener to jtextfield to search contents as soon as something typed on it
addDocumentListener();
```

My documentlistener method,

```
private void addDocumentListener(){
   documentListener = new DocumentListener(){
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent){
           search();
      }

      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent){
           search();
      }

      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent){
           search();
      }

      private void search(){
           searchTableContents(search_field.getText());
      }

   };
}
```

My searching Method,

```
public void searchTableContents(String searchString)
{
    DefaultTableModel currtableModel = (DefaultTableModel) list_table.getModel();
    //To empty the table before search
    currtableModel.setRowCount(0);
    //To search for contents from original table content
    for (Object rows : originalTableModel)
    {
        Vector rowVector = (Vector) rows;
        for (Object column : rowVector)
        {

                if **(column.toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase())**)
                {

                    //content found so adding to table
                    currtableModel.addRow(rowVector);
                    break;
                }


        }
    }
}
```

This is the place where I called this method,

```
private void search_fieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)                                                      
{                                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    searchTableContents(search_field.getText());
}
```

I bold the point where I got this null pointer exception.

Have any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Debug this line, and see which variable is null. My guess it is "searchString"

Comment: @Marcinek : - So then what could I do to recover it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your `column` variable is null. This will be the case if at least one of the cells in the table is empty. Furthermore, since `originalTableModel` is taken as a clone of the table model in the constructor, any changes since the clone was taken till the time `searchTableContents` is run will not be reflected in the `originalTableModel`.

To fix it, you should change the if to `if (column != null && column.toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase()))`.

Comment: What do you mean by "&& ..." ?